# How to prevent moderators from using moderation commands at each other in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

I made a bot in discord.py for my server. It has moderation commands. But I have an issue. If I use for example mute command on a moderator. It gives them the muted role. Same thing applies with kick/ban. Is there any way to stop moderators from using mod commands on other mods?

Comment: An `if` statement to check if the victim has lower roles then the command giver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `>=` and the `top_role` attribute which would compare the roles that the user compared to the member you are attempting to take moderation on, if your permissions are lower than the member you are attempting to moderate, it will prevent the rest of the code running. Here is a simple way of doing this,

```
if member.top_role >= ctx.author.top_role:
    await ctx.send(f"You can only moderate members below your role")         
    return
```

Here is an example using it with a ban or a command you want it with,

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members = True)
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    
    if member.top_role >= ctx.author.top_role:
        await ctx.send(f"You can only moderate members below your role")         
        return

    await member.ban()
```